# Getting code from a .txt on a website and pasting it in a tempfile PYTHON

Tags: python, request, temporary-files

I was trying to make a script that gets a .txt from a websites, pastes the code into a python executable temp file but its not working. Here is the code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as urlopen
import os
import subprocess
import os
import tempfile

filename = urlopen("https://randomsiteeeee.000webhostapp.com/script.txt")
temp = open(filename)
temp.close()
    # Clean up the temporary file yourself
os.remove(filename)

temp = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
temp.close()
```

If you know a fix to this please let me know. The error is :

```
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    temp = open(filename)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not HTTPResponse
```

I tried everything such as a request to the url and pasting it but didnt work as well. I tried the code that i pasted here and didnt work as well.

And as i said, i was expecting it getting the code from the .txt from the website, and making it a temp executable python script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are missing a read:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as urlopen
import os
import subprocess
import os
import tempfile

filename = urlopen("https://randomsiteeeee.000webhostapp.com/script.txt").read() # <-- here
temp = open(filename)
temp.close()
    # Clean up the temporary file yourself
os.remove(filename)

temp = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
temp.close()
```

But if the `script.txt` contains the script and not the filename, you need to create a temporary file and write the content:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as urlopen
import os
import subprocess
import os
import tempfile

content = urlopen("https://randomsiteeeee.000webhostapp.com/script.txt").read() # 
with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as fp:
    name = fp.name
    fp.write(content)
```

If you want to execute the code you fetch from the url, you may also use `exec` or `eval` instead of writing a new script file.
**`eval` and `exec` are EVIL, they should only be used if you 100% trust the input and there is no other way!**

EDIT: How do i use exec?

Using exec, you could do something like this (also, I use requests instead of urllib here. If you prefer urllib, you can do this too):

```
import requests

exec(requests.get("https://randomsiteeeee.000webhostapp.com/script.txt").text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your trying to open a file that is named "the content of a website".

```py
filename = "path/to/my/output/file.txt"
httpresponse = urlopen("https://randomsiteeeee.000webhostapp.com/script.txt").read()
temp = open(filename)
temp.write(httpresponse)
temp.close()
```

Is probably more like what you are intending